# In VSTS, how to move access level from stakeholder to basic access

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, azure-devops

My project in VSTS got some users. For a particular user X i assigned admin access and on his login, Code menu doesn't appear.

On checking settings -> Version Control, it says

> As a stakeholder you can access the backlog, task and kanban boards,
>   work items and manage approvals for releases.

**How to migrate an user from stakeholder access to Basic access?**

> User is not able to access code even from Visual Studio also.

Comment: btw, if anyone is having issue with doing this on installation of TFS, press the gear icon, go to Server settings and then select the Access Levels tab from the top

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VSTS provides with 5 Basic user access, unlimited Visual studio subscriber access and all other's get restricted to Stakeholder access [No access to code]. Find the access comparison [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/compare-features/)

In case if you need to provide Basic user access, you need to remove/modify basic access of an user to stakeholder and assign the required user with Basic access. Only Account collection administrator could do this.

Steps and Screenshots to change access from Neha Gupta to Shalem Raju are provided below:

1. Navigate to https://youraccount.visualstudio.com/_admin/_users
2. Select an Basic user and select - Change Access level
3. Assign this user with Stakeholder
4. Select the desired stakeholder access user and change his/her access to Basic Access

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, there are no seats available with Basic access (you have only 5 free by default) and in this case, VSTS assigns Stakeholder access. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/add-account-users-from-user-hub) for more details.