# Access level - stakeholder vs visual studio user

Tags: azure-devops

Can a user that has a Visual Studio subscription be given only "stakeholder" access?  That way they can still use Visual Studio for their purposes, but as for VSTS and a team project, they can only do things such as enter bugs, get to the kanban boards (and update it if needed), define sprints etc.  Basically "management stuff".

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863308/in-vsts-how-to-move-access-level-from-stakeholder-to-basic-access) help?

Comment: Well, sort of but not really.  I know how to change the access level of a user.  However, will changing the access level of someone from Visual Studio user to Stakeholder affect their use of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> VSTS automatically assigns them Basic features, if your account has
>   seats available, or Stakeholder features, if not.  [-Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/add-account-users-from-user-hub?view=vsts)

What this effectively means is that VSTS will upgrade your user to the highest available license when the user logs in.

- Any unassigned Basic License registered to your account automatically get assigned to stakeholders as they log in. (based on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/add-account-users-from-user-hub?view=vsts))
- The same auto upgrade happens when the user have some sort of MSDN license. (based on personal experience)

So due to the auto upgrade process, trying to keep a user in the Stakeholder License as a means to restrict access might be a losing battle. You might want to modify permissions around this user instead or create a custom security group between Readers and Contributors.